# TypeError: open() missing required argument 'file' (pos 1)

Tags: python

I try to publish a sample question on mturk using Python, so I follow the tutorial and copy their code like follows. However, I always get an Error like:

```
File "C:/Users/jingh/PycharmProjects/test/example.py", line 22, in
<module>
    question = open(name='questions.xml',mode='r').read() 
    TypeError: open() missing required argument 'file' (pos 1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
question = open(name='questions.xml',mode='r').read()
new_hit = client.create_hit(
    Title = 'Is this Tweet happy, angry, excited, scared, annoyed or upset?',
    Description = 'Read this tweet and type out one word to describe the emotion of the person posting it: happy, angry, scared, annoyed or upset',
    Keywords = 'text, quick, labeling',
    Reward = '0.15',
    MaxAssignments = 1,
    LifetimeInSeconds = 172800,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds = 600,
    AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds = 14400,
    Question = question,
)
print ("A new HIT has been created. You can preview it here:")
print ("https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=" + new_hit['HIT']['HITGroupId'])
print ("HITID = " + new_hit['HIT']['HITId'] + " (Use to Get Results)")
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for open method first. The first argument is not `name` but `file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first arguemnt to python `open()` function is `file`. So change this

```
question = open(name='questions.xml',mode='r').read()
```

to

```
question = open(file='questions.xml',mode='r').read()
```

or simply

```
question = open('questions.xml',mode='r').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try: With `with` keyword your file with be normally closed. Saving you from `memory leak`

```
with open('questions.xml','r') as fp:
    myXMLfile=fp.read()
```