# What is the 'flags' argument of the 'open()' function in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a script in Python, that loops through a few pandas dataframes named `df_1` through to `df_6` and then creates a text file in a specified folder and stores some data from the dataframes in the text file for each dataframe. The problem is that I keep getting an error and always on the same line, it's the `with open(path=name(slovar[k]), mode='w') as f:` line and the last error, that I can't seem to solve is `TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)`.

The script:

```
def name(name):
    return 'D:\\FMF\\Fizikalni praktikum III\\Piezoelektricnost\\{}.txt'.format(name)

slovar = {
    1   :   'tezka_obr',
    2   :   'tezka_razbr',
    3   :   'srednja_obr',
    4   :   'srednja_razbr',
    5   :   'lahka_obr',
    6   :   'lahka_razbr'
}

slovar_n = {
    1   :   df_1,
    2   :   df_2,
    3   :   df_3,
    4   :   df_4,
    5   :   df_5,
    6   :   df_6
}

for k in range(1, 7):
    df = slovar_n[k]
    with open(path=name(slovar[k]), mode='w') as f:
        for i in range(1, 1001):
            try:
                if df.iloc[1][1000 * i] - df.iloc[1][0] > 0.01:
                    f.write('{}     {}\n'.format(df.iloc[0][1000 * i], df.iloc[1][1000 * i]))
            except IndexError:
                break
```

Comment: Does changing 'path' to 'file' fix it? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552734/typeerror-open-missing-required-argument-file-pos-1

Comment: Looks like you've somehow overwritten the built-in `open()` function with something else - perhaps a `def open():` somewhere else in your code, perhaps something imported from a module.

Comment: When trying this, I get `missing required argument 'file'`, not `missing required argument 'flags'`.

Comment: Possibly you have `from os import open`, it has a parameter 'flags'.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I deleted the `from os import *` line at the beginning and now it works